# Индикатор выполнения (обновления страницы) в asp.mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, javascript, mvc

Добрый день!
Имеется приложение asp.net mvc для выполнения хранимых процедур из БД. Т.е. пользователь вводит входные параметры, нажимает на submit и после обновления страницы получает результаты. Некоторые хранимки выполняются долго (5-8 минут). Всё это время, висит обновление страницы, т.е. запрос отправлен, но страница висит и ждёт окончания выполнения и потом обновляется. Как на этот промежуток времени повесить какой-нибудь индикатор (проще вращающийся кружок по центру экрана)
Буду очень благодарен за примеры на JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Давай](http://www.cyberguru.ru/microsoft-net/asp-net/locking-screen-postback.html) я [поищу](https://malsup.com/jquery/block/#overview) в [Google](https://www.sitepoint.com/lock-freeze-web-page-jquery/) за [тебя](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506152543/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/121708-1.aspx).

Comment: Благодарю. Что-то я гуглил, но интересных вариантов не нашёл.

Answer (score 2):

Это скрипт. который будет запускать иконку при исполнении ajax

```
$("body").on({ ajaxStart: function () { $(this).addClass("loading"); }, ajaxStop: function () { $(this).removeClass("loading"); } });
```

В стилях прописываешь

```
body.loading
{
    overflow: hidden;
}

    body.loading .modal
    {
        display: block;
    }
```

и еще в разметке добавь

```
<div class="modal"></div>
```